# Prove the following functions are not continuous at c?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity

> for $c = 1$
>
> $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> x^2-1,  & \text{0 < x ≤ 1} \\
> x+3, & \text{x > 1}
> \end{cases}$$

My solution:

Function $f$ is defined at $x=1$ since $f(1)= 1^2-1 = 0$

the left hand limit:
$$\lim_{x\to^- 1}f(x)= 1^2 - 1 = 0$$

the right hand limit:
$$\lim_{x\to^+ 1} f(x) = 1+3 = 4$$

since the left and right hand limits are not equal $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x)$ DNE and condition (2) is not satisfied. thus function $f$ is not continuous

Comment: Yes, that's right. But it's almost the same as the one before. I think you're good enough in this so you can ask something different next time.

Comment: okay thanks just making sure